# UNC path for GRADLE_USER_HOME

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I chnaged GRADLE_USER_HOME system variable to a UNC path to chnage user gradle directory to use downloaded data in offline computers in network but when I build my android studio project, I get this error:

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

How can I fix this error or what can I do for use downloaded gradle cache in offline computers?